# Moodle Activity Quiz Backup from Moodle 3.9 to Moodle 4.2.3

Tags: migration, backup, moodle, restore

I am a moodle user and i use Moodle 3.9 with old installation and Moodle 4.3.2 with new installation or just the update of the old installation.

Now i want to backup the old new quiz questions answers of all students from the old install. to the new install. and i use the backup and restore method but the problem is the backup of 3.9 version is imcompatible and to not be use to restaure in the 4.2.3 version.

If there is anyway to take all mark and question of activity quiz of 3.9 version to put it in the 4.2.3 version, i'm opened to try it. Else if it's exists a way to convert the backup of the old version 3.9 to compatible 4.2.3 version, I'm opened again to try it.

So i need your helps. Thank you for your comprehension.

Comment: Moodle 3.9 backups should be fully compatible with Moodle 4.2, as far as I'm aware. Moodle is usually very careful about allowing this to work (because it's a pretty common use case). I would suggest you investigate further to find out exactly what is going wrong when you try it yourself.

Comment: Ah ok. i wil try again and take notes. thank you.

Comment: Sorry but when i use backup of Moodle 4.2 activity there is no problem with a 3.9 backup the system cannot load the file it's stay in a pending while loop.
I really need to backup it. It's more important